# Поведение элементов в балуне

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Добрый день.

Есть ссылка в контенте балуна в кластере, при клике на неё навешиваю класс к примеру active, и стилизую её, но проблема в том, что когда закрываю балун(кластер) или переключаю слайды в кластере, то класс пропадает, ощущение, что заново все генерится. Есть ли возможность победить фичу эту?

И еще момент, можно ли стилизовать пагинацию как-нибудь для слайдера кластера? Отступы между цифрами, высоты и т.д?

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день. Макет действительно каждый раз пересоздается при открытии балуна. Чтобы кастомизировать его нужно или применять стили при каждом открытии, или сделать собственный макет балуна. Второй вариант сложнее, но правильней.

Comment: Спасибо за оперативный ответ, но немного не поняли наверное Вы меня. Я использую собственный макет балуна, но при закрытии содержимое пропадает из DOM, следовательно при очередном открытии мой макет генерируется заново (как я вижу по DOM структуре) значит и класс который навешивался на клик по элементу   в содержимом при очередном открытии балуна пропадает. 

Вот пример пользовательского макета https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_autopan при закрытии балуна содержимое пропадает из DOM - или я туплю где-то 8) ?

Comment: P.S. 
И еще момент, можно ли стилизовать пагинацию как-нибудь для слайдера кластера? Отступы между цифрами, высоты и т.д?

Comment: Понял. Вам надо тогда надо не просто класс навешивать, а менять state кластера. При изменении состояния надо как раз менять класс. Ну и нужно проверять значение из state при открытии. Примерно как в этом примере https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_balloon_layout
(ну только к state.*** надо обращаться вместо properties).

Ответ на второй вопрос - нет. У макетов балуна кластера очень мало опций. https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ClusterPlacemark-docpage/#param-options.balloonContentLayout

Comment: Понял Вас, но после нескольких часов танцев с бубном я вспотел. 

Вы не могли бы кусок кода скинуть как грамотно проверять state балуна при открытии и как его же менять по клику на какой-нибудь элемент из содержимого балуна. Спасибо за терпение.

Comment: Переделал пример https://jsfiddle.net/tb9fzxkz/ Теперь counter содержится непосредственно в state геообъекта.